# " You don't have permission to access the file or folder" on shared folder

Tags: file-sharing

I'm not exactly new to this, but this a new problem for me.

The shared folder is configured to be accessed only by one administrator account. I was able to access it before, but now I'm getting this error :

[image]

Same thing happens with shared folders on some other computers, but not all of them. Also I am able to access \\XXX-PC\Desktop from a second computer, so it's not a share configuration problem.

I know you can have only one network session so I restarted this computer (it has worked before when I tried to connect with a second account), but no change.

The windows credential manager is empty:

[image]

and I am able to access the computer itself :

[image]

It looks like my computer is trying to connect with another account, but I dont know why or how to stop it.

OS in this computer is windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`net use \\XXX-PC\Desktop /delete` in `cmd` ended the previous connection and it was then possible to connect using the administrator account. Current connections can be listed in `cmd` by simply typing `net use`. It's also possible to use `net use * /delete` to end all connections. This last one should be similar to a simple restart.

For some reason I had to play with these commands for a while until I was able to establish connections to the shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue since last fall and have tried all the other proposed solutions I've found on the web. It seems like there can be more than one cause for this problem since some solutions work for some people but not others.

None of the solutions I found on the web worked for me, so on a whim, I manually created Windows Credentials for all the computers on our business network. From the Control Panel, select Credential Manager. Select the tab on the right side that says Windows Credentials. Click on 'Add a Windows credential'. For 'Internet or network address' I entered \computer-name. I then entered the user name (administrator access) and password for the user on that particular computer. I created a new credential for each computer on our network, and just to be safe, I created a credential for the computer I was on, too. I did the same for every computer on our network. So what I ended up with is 5 computers, each with 5 Windows Credentials, one for each of the other computers and one for itself.

This finally solved my 'You do not have permission to access...' problem.